# How to show code coverage on Unity3D unit testing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, rider

I wrote some unit tests to my scripts in Unity3D. Is there any way to show code coverage? I run tests with Unity Test Runner and working on VS for Mac.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't used unity 2018, so am not sure how nUnit is integrated with it. But maybe you want to check out if [Ncover](http://www.ncover.com/) would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Code Coverage package, available in 2019.3 and above (can also be installed in 2019.2 but it is unsupported). For more details see the official blog post here https://forum.unity.com/threads/code-coverage-package-preview.777542/